# How to pass user object into forms field

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to pass a user object from my views.py into my forms.py to the user field and save a new object. The user field is a foreign key in the model. I can do a select dropdown widget like with the jobSite field but im trying to automatically pass the user object on submit instead of the current user having to select another user from the drop down. I've tried passing the user through as an initial key value from the views.py like so

```
form = entryTime(request.POST, initial={'user': user})
```

I've tried a few different variations of that but so far haven't been able to successfully get the user object to save to the user field.

forms.py

```
class entryTime(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = [
            'user',
            'start_time',
            'end_time',
            'jobSite',

        ]
        widgets = {
            'start_time': DateTimePicker(
                    options={'useCurrent': True, 'collapse': False},
                    attrs={'append': 'fa fa-calendar', 'icon_toggle': True}
                ),
            'end_time': DateTimePicker(
                    options={'useCurrent': True, 'collapse': False},
                    attrs={'append': 'fa fa-calendar', 'icon_toggle': True}
                ),
            'jobSite': Select()
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(entryTime, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['start_time'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['end_time'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['jobSite'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

views.py

```
def addTimeEntry(request, userId):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=userId)

    form = entryTime()

    if request.POST:
        form = entryTime(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('form is valid')

    args={"form":form}
    return render(request, 'timesheets/addTimeEntry.html', args)
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not *have* to pass this as initial data. You can simply set the `user` attribute of the `instance` of the form in your view. You can thus omit the `user` field in your `EntryTimeForm`. I suggest you add a `Form` suffix, since otherwise it can easily introduce "name clashes":

```
class entryTimeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        _dt_options = {'useCurrent': True, 'collapse': False}
        _dt_attrs = {'append': 'fa fa-calendar', 'icon_toggle': True, 'class': 'form-control'}
        fields = [ 'start_time', 'end_time', 'jobSite']
        widgets = {
            'start_time': DateTimePicker(options=_dt_options, attrs=_dt_attrs),
            'end_time': DateTimePicker(options=_dt_options, attrs=_dt_attrs),
            'jobSite': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

and then set the `user` attribute in your view:

```
def addTimeEntry(request, userId):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=userId)
    if request.POST:
        form = EntryTimeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = user
            form.save()
            return redirect('some_view')
    else:
        form = EntryTimeForm()
    args={'form': form}
    return render(request, 'timesheets/addTimeEntry.html', args)
```

You can even omit fetching the `user` object and thus reduce the number of queries with one with:

```
def addTimeEntry(request, userId):
    if request.POST:
        form = EntryTimeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user_id = userId
            form.save()
            return redirect('some_view')
    else:
        form = EntryTimeForm()
    args={'form': form}
    return render(request, 'timesheets/addTimeEntry.html', args)
```